# How to create scrolling text in A-frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am working in A-frame and I need scrolling text to display on top of a 3d object. From preliminary research, html css does not work in a-frame. Can scrolling text still be accomplished? How can i use css in a-frame? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html can be embedded in Aframe (but it is not built in).
Use this component by superEggbert
https://github.com/supereggbert/aframe-htmlembed-component

Scrolling text is a bit more involved (don't think you get it automatically with aframe-htmlembed-component, but I haven't used it yet, so not sure).

Here is a tutorial that walks through making a VR blog in Aframe.
Towards the bottom it gets into how to make a giant slab of scrolling text.

https://www.nateliason.com/blog/vr-blog

Also worth noting that you can have screen space html that sits on top of your aframe scene. It's not very attractive, but that is one way to add scrolling text on top of your 3D scene.